# FAILED: ninja: unknown target 'MODULES-IN-vendor-xxx-yyy

Tags: android

Getting error while doing "mm" in individual project of android inside vendor folder.

error : FAILED: ninja: unknown target 'MODULES-IN-vendor-xxx-yyy'

I am using Android 10 so adding optional_subdirs does not working.